# Is it possible to make use of Vim's clientserver feature without GUI?

Tags: vim

I've compiled Vim with Homebrew (OS X) like that:

```
brew install vim --with-client-server
```

And the `--version` request indeed confirms it:

```
a @ ~> /usr/local/bin/vim --version | grep serv
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
```

Besides, just in case, it has X11 support, too:

```
a @ ~> /usr/local/bin/vim --version | grep X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind       +X11
```

However, if I start Vim with the servername option like this: `/usr/local/bin/vim --servername foo`, asking then vim in another shell to enlist active servers returns just nothing:

```
 a @ ~> /usr/local/bin/vim --serverlist
 a @ ~>
```

Thus, I wonder, is it possible at all to use the client-server feature in the console mode, without GUI? Any positive feedback available?

Comment: I believe vim clientserver needs a running X-Server. Do you have one running, when trying this?

Comment: Actually, I've tried that within [XQuartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuartz), too, and the results were the same.

Comment: You need either a working X clipboard, or Windows clipboard.  Thus, no, it won't work in console.

Comment: is the comment above from @SatoKatsura the official answer then?

Answer (score 2):

The help tells:

```
The communication between client and server goes through the X server.
```

(found with `help client-server`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

I'll write all the steps needed

1. `brew cask install xquartz`
2. Launch XQuartz. You might need to update it. (This step is missing for you)
3. Logout and login, or restart your Mac.
4. `brew install vim --with-client-server`

Now if you launch vim, XQuartz will be launched as well. And if you run vim with `--servername <name>` argument, you will be able to see the server using `--serverlist` option.

But after this, you have to launch XQuartz with vim, and also you have to do some work for making clipboard work well vim. I found [a blog post](http://www.markcampbell.me/2016/04/12/setting-up-yank-to-clipboard-on-a-mac-with-vim.html) and followed the it but failed to make it work correctly regarding the clipboard.

Comment: So is it possible or not?

Comment: @arcseldon client/server feature itself is possible, but you might face some issues.

Comment: Thanks, yes - I got eclim working with Java Debugging support (using eclim 2.7.1) but had to resort to using MacVim, rather than vim 8 / neovim which I use most of the time.