# Vim with +clientserver feature on Mac OS M1

Tags: macos, vim, apple-m1

Can Vim's `+clientserver` feature be used on MacOS 12.2.1? I have Vim installed `+clientserver` feature on, but the `--serverlist` and `--servername <name>` flags do not work.

I don't mind compiling Vim from source or using a GUI package of Vim. Nor do I mind using xquartz if that is necessary. If this is not possible on MacOS 12 to get this feature working on MacOS, any workarounds using other packages or Vim plugins that provide similar functionality would be welcome.

**Note**: This question is similar to these two questions:

- [Compile Vim 7.3 with +clientserver feature on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231223/compile-vim-7-3-with-clientserver-feature-on-mac-os-x)
- [Is it possible to make use of Vim's clientserver feature without GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061388/is-it-possible-to-make-use-of-vims-clientserver-feature-without-gui)

The most recent answer on both of these is from 2016 and no longer works on MacOS 12 so I don't think this should be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

[MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim) has the `+clientserver` feature but only the GUI can act as a server while both the GUI and the TUI can act as clients.

Once MacVim is installed, check out `:help macvim-clientserver`.

Comment: I see. Ideally I'd like the server to be an instance of Vim running in the terminal. Is that not possible at all?

Comment: Not with MacVim because it manages this through a feature of the GUI toolkit. Maybe with a manual build, along with xquartz.